Android SDK 34 Dexpathlist Error with Java
I'm currently trying to migrate a legacy Java app from SDK 33 > 34 but I run into the following error with a common library module I use with all my apps.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/brandname/lib/CustomClass;
at com.brandname.javaapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8342)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.brandname.lib.CustomClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file...
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
...

Using AGP 8.5.1 and Gradle 8.7, the settings are as follows.
build.gradle(:app)
dependencies {

    implementation project(path: ':Lib')

settings.gradle
rootProject.name = "JavaApp"
include ':app'

include ':Lib'
project(':Lib').projectDir = new File('../CommonCode/lib')
// module uses package name, com.brandname.lib

Module Code
package com.brandname.lib;

public class CustomClass {
}

The app builds fine, no errors. Only during runtime it crashes.
I don't have this issue when migrating my Kotlin apps and the stack trace isn't of any help. Does anyone know what's causing this?
I read about enabling multidex support but it doesn't help. I'm certain it doesn't go beyond the 64K methods limit that would cause a multidex splitting issue and I don't get that error when compiling anyway.
